# Como atribuir um operador matemático a uma variável

Tags: powershell

Quero atribuir um operador matemático (`+`, `-`, `/` e `*`) a uma variável, para construir expressões dinâmicas.

Por exemplo:

```
$operator = '+'
$calculation = [int](1 $operator 1)
Write-Host calculation
```

O resultado deve ser `2`.

Answer (score 3):

Continue fazendo a atribuição do operador matemático como uma string.

Para aproveitar o operador matemático em uma expressão dinâmica,  uma solução é criar um [bloco de script](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.1) que aceite como parâmetro um operador aritmético e dois operandos numéricos, então esse bloco de script constrói uma string contendo uma expressão coerente e a executa com [`Invoke-Expression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.1).

Deixando claro que a documentação do cmdlet `Invoke-Expression` faz o seguinte alerta :

> Tome uma razoável precauções ao usar a cmdlet `Invoke-Expression` em scripts.
> Ao usar `Invoke-Expression` para executar um comando inserido pelo usuário,
> verifique se o comando é seguro para execução antes de executá-lo.
> Em geral, é melhor projetar seu script com opções de entrada predefinidas, em
> vez de permitir a entrada de forma livre.

Um bloco de script é uma coleção de instruções ou expressões que podem ser usadas como uma única unidade.
Um bloco de script pode aceitar argumentos e retornar valores.

Nesse caso o bloco de script aceita três argumentos `$p1`, `$opr` e `$p2`, onde  :

- `$p1` e `$p2` são operandos numéricos.
- `$opr` é um [operador aritmético (`+`, `-`, `/` e `*`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#arithmetic-operators).

Quando chamado o bloco de script monta e executa o resultado da expressão:

```
$p1 $opr $p2
```

Para executar um bloco de script use o [operador de chamadas &](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-) que permite executar comandos armazenados em variáveis, representados strings ou blocos de script.

***Alerta**: que o código a seguir não faz nenhuma validação dos parâmetros `$p1`, `$opr` e `$p2`, caso seus valores sejam buscados fora do script implemente um sistema de validação dos argumentos:*

```powershell
$dexpr = { param($p1, $opr, $p2)
   Invoke-Expression "$p1 $opr $p2"
}

$operator = '+'
$calculation = &$dexpr 1 $operator 1
Write-Host $calculation
```

<sup>[Teste o exemplo online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3BCsIwDAbge58ijOIU3WHedxTmE3gOM@CwLiGtbiA@e23rDubwH8L3J8Izqb@RczHaKy2i0MEbBBUfWyvtASyLppTjzsBvztOL79ScEibvR56gSrLA7KriPsakBSkGzifrfW3sgG54Ogy50sFm/VeaK2zNRcdATc8@wL@P8Qs)</sup>

Comment: Muito Obrigado! @Augusto Vasques, mas e quando minha lista de números for extensa?

Por exemplo: 3803+3821+3823+3833+3847+3851+3853+3863...

Comment: No caso use de associatividade para encadear as operação `$calculation = &$dexpr (&$dexpr 1 $operator 1) $operator 1` . Mas en todo caso é uma nova pergunta que foge a proposta inicial.